# Where can I configure the timeout of JBoss cluster node drop?

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing

We have 4 nodes clustering. When one of them has a long GC pause, then this causes the note to be dropped from clustering and generating the following log:

> 2012-06-14 03:27:48,277 INFO  [org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.postoffice.GroupMember] org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.postoffice.GroupMember$ControlMembershipListener@6225352b got new view [10.164.218.18:7910|10] [10.164.218.18:7910, 10.164.107.69:7910, 10.164.107.65:7910], old view is [10.164.218.14:7910|9] [10.164.218.14:7910, 10.164.218.18:7910, 10.164.107.69:7910, 10.164.107.65:7910]
>   2012-06-14 03:27:48,277 INFO  [org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.postoffice.GroupMember] I am (10.164.218.18:7910)
>   2012-06-14 03:27:48,998 INFO  [org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.postoffice.MessagingPostOffice] JBoss Messaging is failing over for failed node 52. If there are many messages to reload this may take some time...

I would like to configure the timeout of the node drop. It seems to be 2 minutes in my case and I would like to increase it, but I can't find where to configure it.

Where can I configure the timeout of JBoss cluster node drop?

Answer (score 0):

I found it, it in oracle-persistence-service.xml. You need to adjust the configurations in 
ControlChannelConfig section. I think it is the 'timeout' of 'FD' protocol.